# Deploying Aurelia Apps with gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, aurelia

I'm having some issues deploying my first Aurelia app using the 'gulp' process outlined in the Aurelia documentation [here](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/bundling-your-app-for-deploy/1). I started developing it using the Aurelia provided ES 2016 Kit. After installing aurelia-bundler and gulp through npm and creating the bundle.js file, gulp states that no gulpfile was found when running the 'gulp bundle' command.

I tried renaming bundle.js to gulpfile.js. It then threw errors about unable to find an injectionConfigPath (which is talked about further down under Bundling a JSPM v0.17 App).

Do I need to follow the 0.17 process and instead name bundle.js => gulpfile.js against the documentation? Or do I have something setup wrong?

Comment: are you using skeleton navigation? are you running gulp bundle from the root folder?

Comment: I don't think I'm using the skeleton navigation - I started with whatever is downloadable from the Aurelia 'Getting Started' article inside the main documentation / API website. I've tried running gulp bundle from both root and inside build/tasks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bundling documentation assumes you are working from the skeleton as your base. Specifically `skeleton-esnext` or `skeleton-typescript`. If you download the latest release of the skeletons you can use one of those two skeletons as the starting point for your app, or you can try using one of the webpack skeletons (and thus learning Webpack).

You should be able to transition quite quickly, just delete the src folder in the skeleton you're going to use, and replace it with the src folder from your app. You'll also need to copy any dependencies, whether npm or (more likely) jspm from your existing app to the skeleton. You can then run `npm install` and `jspm install` then `gulp bundle`.

The kit you download on the Getting Started page is positioned to serve simply as a tool to help you work your way through the Getting Started guide without having to futz around with the crazy, mixed-up world that is Modern JavaScript tooling. It doesn't provide the full suite of tooling that our skeletons offer, or that our CLI will (very soon).

Quick edit: Downloading the skeletons and working from them is mentioned in "[A Production Setup](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/a-production-setup)."

Comment: I had to add 'use strict' at the top of the gulpfile.js included in skeleton-esnext, but that seemed to get it to work, thanks! For some reason it isn't copying in the aurelia-*.js files into /dist, so I manually copied what was missing in and everything looks good. config.js npm: paths all point correctly to where they exist. Is there something I missed to get those to copy in?

Comment: What version of node are you running? This in regards to the 'use strict' part.

Comment: Where are `aurelia.js` and `app-build.js being generated? https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/blob/master/skeleton-esnext/build/bundles.js#L3 tells the bundler where to put the files

Comment: node version 4.4.1; sorry, I wasn't totally clear on my comment. I'm running 'gulp watch' for now which is what isn't pulling in the aurelia-* files into /dist.  When I continued on in the documentation for 'gulp bundle', app-build.js was generated into /dist, however it failed on vendor-build.js =>  Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\EPA\skeleton-esnext\jspm_packages\github\aurelia\templating-binding.js'. I'm not sure why it's looking there when the config.js states npm:aurelia-*

Comment: vendor-build? There's no such file being created in the skeleton's gulp tasks. There's `aurelia.js` and `app-build.js`.

Comment: I was looking at http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/bundling-your-app-for-deploy/2 around Bundling an Aurelia Application - gulp bundle resulting in app-build and vendor-build. Not generating an aurelia.js though using gulp bundle.

Comment: Ah, yeah. I would recommend using the gulp tasks from the skeleton for right now. We're going to be updating that documentation in the next couple of days.

Comment: Ah k will do. I'm at least at a point right now where developing alongside gulp watch working is all I need. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Figured I'd follow up and mention the new skeleton and guide works perfectly :)